# Does live paypal classic api credentials expire?

Tags: api, paypal

Hi I got live paypal classic api credentials(like api username, signature, api password).

will this ever expire? or it will stay same until i reset the credential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These credentials do not expire unless you remove them from your account for any reason. If you do remove them, you would need to request new credentials and update your site.

Comment: thank you. this is the same answer i got from Paypal account manager.